# adding a text over an image in python using imagemagik/PIL

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library, python, python-2.7

I have a text say "I am doing great". I want to put this text over a lovely background which i have generated. 
I want to put `"I am doing great"` over an image `"image.jpg"` present in the system. 
The starting point of the text should be X, y in pixels.

i tried the following snippet, but am having error:
Snippet:

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf",40)
text = "Sample Text"
tcolor = (255,0,0)
text_pos = (100,100)

img = Image.open("certificate.png")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text(text_pos, text, fill=tcolor, font=font)
del draw

img.save("a_test.png")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "img_man.py", line 13, in <module>
    draw.text(text_pos, text, fill=tcolor, font=font)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 256, in text
    ink, fill = self._getink(fill)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 145, in _getink
    ink = self.palette.getcolor(ink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImagePalette.py", line 62, in getcolor
    self.palette = map(int, self.palette)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\xed'
```

seems to be a bug in PIL:
http://grokbase.com/t/python/image-sig/114k20c9re/perhaps-bug-report

Is there any workaround i can try?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same bug, it seems to be a bug in Pil/Pillow with PNG palette handling. The workaround is to convert your image to RBG before drawing the text:

```
img = img.convert('RGB')
```

Comment: Thanks ! I was struggling with the same (or a very similar) issue and converting the image did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `text` method of [the `ImageDraw` module](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm) (top Google hit for 'pil text'.) You'll also need the [`ImageFont`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagefont.htm) module, which sports relevant example code:

```
import ImageFont, ImageDraw
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 15)
draw.text((10, 10), "hello", font=font)
```

Comment: this mentions how to draw, not how to write text. Would you like to draw letters? Im not for typograpfy using pil.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand the distinction between drawing text onto an image and writing text onto an image.

Comment: @user993563 That error message seems kind of byzantine but I believe it has to do with `tcolor` given where the exception actually happens (`ImagePalette.py, line 62, in getcolor`)

Comment: seems that is a bug in PIL http://grokbase.com/t/python/image-sig/114k20c9re/perhaps-bug-report any workaround??